# LocalStorage is randomly changed after application restart

Tags: android, android-webview, local-storage

Api 14. I have this simple settings

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(webView.getContext().getDir("databases",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
```

I store some value in localStorage
localStorage.musicVolume
First time I run the application I set musicVolume to 7
I have close button which call System.exit(1);
So I can restart the application several times without any problem, musicVolume is restored as 7.
But then one time musicVolume is 0, so I set it to 3.
And now I have weird situation when absolutely randomly after restart, musicValue can be restored as 3 or 7. It looks like there is somehow two localStorages for same application.
Any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use sharedpreferences?

Comment: It's web application which already use localStorage